# Disable few checkboxes based on a condition in Vaadin Grid Multi selection

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin24

Does someone know how can I disable few checkboxes when using Vaadin Grid with MULTI selection mode.

I tried to look in the SelectionModel and Vaadin documentation but didn't find anything. Also, tried to google but didn't find anything related to it.

I don't want to go with the solution where i am manually creating the header checkbox and individual checkboxes in each row. it doesn't look great :D

If there is already a solution available in latest Vaadin versions or some neat hack, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you be more precise with the question. What you mean by "few"? Condiitional selection like this https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-conditional-select

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.